# AttributeError when accessing method from ListAdapter in kivy app using screenmanager

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, listadapter, attributeerror

I have the following code causing an AttributeError when calling the method open_project from a button in a ListAdapter.

AttributeError: 'AppScreenManager' object has no attribute 'open_project'

How can I access the open_project method in the class HomeScreen from the current screen?

In main.py I create the app:

```
from kivy.app import App
from manager import AppScreenManager
from startscreen import StartScreen
from kivy.core.window import Window

class PdesignerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = AppScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(StartScreen())
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":          
    PdesignerApp().run()
```

File manager.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

class AppScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

File startscreen.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_file('startscreen.kv')

class StartScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StartScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start, 1)

    def start(self, *args):
         if not self.manager.has_screen('HomeScreen'):
             from homescreen import HomeScreen
             self.manager.add_widget(HomeScreen())
         self.manager.current = 'HomeScreen'
```

File startscreen.kv

```
<StartScreen>:
    name: 'StartScreen'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Image:
            source: './images/splash-foto.jpg'
```

Then in the file homescreen.py, I have the following code fragments in same sequence:

```
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton

class ProjectButton(ListItemButton):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    #and some definitions here etc.

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #and a list of initialisations here

    def open_project(self, project):
        #and quite some processing code here
```

In the file homescreen.kv I have the following:

```
# File: homescreen.kv
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#: import homescreen homescreen
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

<ProjectButton>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: './images/ProjList-sel.png'
    on_release: app.root.open_project(self.text)

<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'HomeScreen'
    project_results_list: project_results_list

    BoxLayout:
        ListView:
            id: project_results_list
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=[], args_converter=lambda row_index,
                            an_obj: {'text': an_obj,'size_hint_y': None,'height': 25},
                            cls=homescreen.ProjectButton)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is here in homescreen.kv:

```
    on_release: app.root.open_project(self.text)
```

it won't work because `app.root` is your `ScreenManager`, not your `HomeScreen`, for it to work, you need to call `open_project` on a reference to your `HomeScreen`, now, i don't see the kv code instanciating `HomeScreen`, but you could give it an id, and use `app.root.ids.home_screen`, but there is another way, since `ScreenManager` gives a way to get a reference to a screen, by name.

```
    on_release: app.root.get_screen('HomeScreen').open_project(self.text)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your clear answer and the insights. Now I understand how to get references to screens. Thanks again.